# How to compile multiple C file with single Makefile in OpenWRT?

Tags: makefile, openwrt, opkg

I am having multiple 'C' files in '/home/user/openwrt/package/utils/C_script/src/one.c two.c three.c upto ten.c in the same path. Inside I have written Makefile to compile C files in order. Like

```
one: one.c
    $(CC) $(LDFLAG) -o one one.c
two: two.c
    $(CC) $(LDFLAG) -o two two.c
```

upto ten files.
How to write Makefile in openWRT to compile 10 files individually and bring 10 individual ipk package and push all the 10 executable in /usr/local/bin.

Comment: You could start with [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules).

Comment: Thanks @Renaud.Now out of that 10 files one file needs a extra flag as pthread. If i pass the argument in the compilation as -pthread, first file itself failing as there is not pthread.h available.Out of that 10 files only one file is requires -pthread argument. How to compile using pattern rules.

Comment: This is where [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) enter the picture.